# Check two table's records are in the same order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two recordset (temp table data) with some columns. I need to check that both table's records are in the **same order**.

I am not checking differences between two recordset or common rows. I need to check that they are in the same order.(both tables have records order by some columns already and need to check order of both tables are same using GUID column)

If Guid matches then I will insert information in some table and if not then into log table, but it should move to/compare next record in both cases.

I am thinking to nested loop for both temp tables and check the order by comparing Guid columns.

Any other approach?

Comment: SQL tables are modeled after unordered sets of records, for all intents and purposes.  There is no internal "order" as you imagine it.  The only order is the one you impose when you add an `ORDER BY` clause to a query.

Comment: The only way to guarantee the order of a set of rows is to use an `ORDER BY` clause in your sql.

Comment: My temp table records  are already ordered. I need to check they are in same order....

Comment: When you populate the tmp tables, you can insert the records in the order you want using the order by clause. I don't see the issue here.

Comment: As pointed above order by is your friend. But in order to understand completely you can share some sample and output expected.

Comment: Ok, there is one table T1 which is prefilled by some scheduler process. Now I have generated resultset using some complex query and inserted into table T2.
I need to check that both data are in same order.
 T1 table, first record, guid = T2 table, first record,guid. 
T1 table, second record,guid=T2 table,second record, guid

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do both tables contain exactly the same data?

Comment: No..they are not same. Only few columns values will be same..one and main of them is Guid

Comment: For the third time a table has no order.  VTC

Comment: @vibs Could you please explain why you need this. Maybe if we get a clear picture of your goals, we might be able to help. This ORDER BY discussion is going nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. Just some hard facts:

- There is **no implicit order!** You can fill your table in a given order and the next `SELECT` might return the data exactly in this order - but this is random! You should **never rely on a sort order!** There is none!
- The only guaranteed way to enforce a sort order is to use `ORDER BY` on the **outermost** query.
- One specialty might be the usage of sorting functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`. But this is to broad to discuss this here.

If I get you correctly, you need to check for rows existing on both sides, if they appear in the same order. Try this:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(YourGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Descr VARCHAR(100),SomeSortableColumn DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('653E6A93-3EBA-4D5E-A8F3-C36462A55FEF','Row 1',{d'2018-01-01'})
                     ,('5461F417-1D14-4CFE-822D-3F028492F839','Row 2',{d'2018-01-02'})
                     ,('E9BDE8C6-237A-49F6-88BD-9EB211FB12F2','Row 3',{d'2018-01-03'})
                     ,('64343D33-8AD2-475F-AC27-66A6BFD011C9','Row 4',{d'2018-01-04'})
                     ,('5778229D-B20E-41FC-9A2E-8694B204E4D3','Row 5',{d'2018-01-05'})
                     ,('9AC0BB10-0F70-488C-A249-45A3C688D877','Row 6',{d'2018-01-06'})
                     ,('330526D6-B931-4CEA-BB03-30F3783E6284','Row 7',{d'2018-01-07'})
                     ,('6F68F260-2F64-4C78-9DA5-20E0FF22B4A1','Row 8',{d'2018-01-08'})
                     ,('E09090F1-FC85-41EE-819B-8275A22BD075','Row 9',{d'2018-01-09'});

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(YourGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Descr VARCHAR(100),SomeSortableColumn DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('653E6A93-3EBA-4D5E-A8F3-C36462A55FEF','Row 1',{d'2018-01-01'})
                     ,('5461F417-1D14-4CFE-822D-3F028492F839','Row 2',{d'2018-01-02'})
                     --missing in 2: 3 & 4
                     ,('5778229D-B20E-41FC-9A2E-8694B204E4D3','Row 5',{d'2018-01-05'})
                     --other GUID  
                     ,(NEWID(),'Row 6',{d'2018-01-06'})
                     ,('330526D6-B931-4CEA-BB03-30F3783E6284','Row 7',{d'2018-01-07'})
                     --other date
                     ,('6F68F260-2F64-4C78-9DA5-20E0FF22B4A1','Row 8',{d'2018-01-01'})
                     ,('E09090F1-FC85-41EE-819B-8275A22BD075','Row 9',{d'2018-01-09'})
                     --missing in 1
                     ,(NEWID(),'Other row',{d'2018-01-03'})
;
```

--This query uses an `INNER JOIN` on the `GUID` column to omit rows, which do not exist in both sets. And it uses two times `ROW_NUMBER()`, each call sorted after the same column, but taken from different sources. The result shows rows where these indexes are different.

```
WITH ColumnsToCompare AS
(
    SELECT t1.YourGuid
          ,t1.Descr AS Descr1
          ,t2.Descr AS Descr2
          ,t1.SomeSortableColumn AS Sort1
          ,t2.SomeSortableColumn AS Sort2
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.SomeSortableColumn) AS Index1
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t2.SomeSortableColumn) AS Index2
    FROM @t1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.YourGuid =t2.YourGuid 
)
SELECT *
FROM ColumnsToCompare
WHERE Index1<>Index2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for you found my question unclear. Well, your answer did not give me what I wanted BUT it was very near and helped me to figure out what I needed. You are awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right but below is what I think you should do.

The below is from your question
"If Guid matches then I will insert information in some table and if not then into log table, but it should move to/compare next record in both cases."

You need 2 insert statements

In the first one, do an inner join on GUIDs and insert the result to table1.

In the second query, do the left join and filter it by null and then insert the result set in to the log table.

```
insert into sometable
select * 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on T1.GUID = T2.GUID

insert into logtable
select * 
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on T1.GUID = T2.GUID
where t2.guid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate row numbers (without ordering) and check for the GUIDs having different row numbers.

```
    declare @table1 table(id varchar(MAX))
    declare @table2 table(id VARCHAR(MAX))

    insert into @table1
    select '653E6A93'
    union all
    select '5461F417'
    union all
    select '330526D6'

    insert into @table2
    select '653E6A93'
    union all
    select '330526D6'
    union all
    select '5461F417'


    ;with cte1
    AS
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS rn from @table1
    )
    ,

    cte2
    AS
    (
        select *, row_number() OVER(order by (SELECT NULL)) rn from @table2
    )

    select c1.id from cte1 c1
    JOIN cte2 c2 on c1.id=c2.id and c1.rn<>c2.rn
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is also somewhat near to my requirement.